# IIS site not visible under 80 port

Tags: iis, bindings

I have 2 bindings for IIS site:

```
 IP Address = * Port = 80
 IP Address = * Port = 100
```

I am able see website as localhost:100 but not as localhost:80 (in the case of port 80 I just see default IIS page).

Also I have allowed port 80 in inbound firewall rules and verified that port 80 is not blocked by any other application. Any Idea? Thanks.

Comment: Past your `netstat -a | find "LISTENING"` here just to verify.

Comment: Is there another site with the same bindings?

Comment: I'm with MichelZ on this one.  I'm guessing you have the Default Web Site, and then whatever you've called your other site, along with possibly more sites than this?  I know it sounds elementary and like the first thing you should (and you probably have) check, but make sure the default site's bindings are not on * & 80.  One way you can alleviate this if you want multiple sites on 80 is to assign multiple IPs to this server and then give the default Web Site an IP binding of port 80 and your other site a different IP but still with port 80 bound.  Hopefully that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said you checked, but until there's verified evidence, you may still have another service already listening on port 80. Check for any other services listening on port 80 thusly:

```
netstat -a | find "LISTENING"
```

Furthermore, just to confirm that the firewall rules are working as you expect, use telnet from both your server and another host (telnet *client*, not telnet ***server***. Don't let anyone tell you that telnet is bad... as long as you're only using the client.)

`telnet your.server.ip.address 80`

You should see something like:

```
telnet 1.1.1.1 80
Trying 1.1.1.1...
Connected to 1.1.1.1
Escape character is '^]'.
```

And then you can try a simple `GET`

`GET / HTTP/1.0`